# How to get parent class name using getClass().getSuperclass()?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the parent class name using

```
public class ClassA  extends Draw{

    public ClassA(){
        super();
    }
    .....

} 
 public class ClassC {

    public getParent(Object a_class)
    {

        String superClass= a_class.getClass().getSuperclass().toString();

    }

}
```

I have got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at Draw.<init>(Draw.java:2)
    at ClassA.<init>(ClassA.java:2)
    at ClassA.<init>(ClassA.java:5)
    at ClassA.<init>(ClassA.java:5)
    at ClassA.<init>(ClassA.java:5)
    at ClassA.<init>(ClassA.java:5)
```

How to get the parent class Name 
I need a parent Class name How to get

Comment: How can we tell without the surce code for Draw.java and ClassA.java? Stackoverflow is no riddle and puzzle site!

Comment: Javadoc says : `If this {@code Class} represents either the {@code Object} class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then null is returned`. Are you trying to get the superclass of a primitive?

Comment: Why `ClassA a_class=new ClassA();` in `getParent(ClassA a_class)`?

Comment: The stacktrace shows that the constructor of ClassA is recursively calling itself. Please show us this constructor.

Comment: I need a parent Class name How to get

Answer (score 12):

Use [`Class.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29):

```
String superClass = a_class.getClass().getSuperclass().getName();
```

To get just the name and not the package name, use [`Class.getSimpleName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29):

```
String superClass = a_class.getClass().getSuperclass().getSimpleName();
```

However, `a_class` is already a `Class` instance so you might want to use `a_class.getSuperclass()` instead.

Comment: i have got same error

Answer (score 4):

I think you just want

```
super.getClass().getName();
```

or possibly

```
super.getClass().getCanonicalName();
```

or, you could use

```
this.getClass().getSuperclass().getName(); // <-- or getCanonicalName()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
super.getClass().getName(); or
yourClass.getClass().getSuperclass().getName();
```

should work fine